# How to copy the contents from one file to another in a single line in java in a single line

Tags: java

So what my code does is, checks whether the file has certain number of columns. if the columns are less than the specified amount of columns it adds the string "null" from the next line.
Furthermore, the code copies the content in file "text" using org.apache.io and puts it into new file named "test".
(content in file "text is in two rows").
I want the content to be shown in file "test" in a single line.

```
    package MySQL;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.*;

public class Add {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\dhruv\\Desktop\\Practicals\\IntelliJ\\src\\MySQL\\text.txt");
        Scanner scanner = null;

        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int number = 0;
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            number = scanner.nextLine().split(" ").length;
        }
        System.out.println(number);

        scanner.close();

        if (number < 10) {

            FileWriter bw_1 = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\dhruv\\Desktop\\Practicals\\IntelliJ\\src\\MySQL\\text.txt", true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(bw_1);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10-number; i++)
            {
                out.write("Null");
                out.write(" ");

            }
            out.close();
        }
        File file_1 = new File("C:\\Users\\dhruv\\Desktop\\Practicals\\IntelliJ\\src\\MySQL\\text.txt");

        String content = null;
        try {
            content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(content);

        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\dhruv\\Desktop\\Practicals\\IntelliJ\\src\\MySQL\\test.txt");
        //String contents = ;

        try {
            Files.writeString(path, content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }



    }
}
```

["text" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX01T.png)

Comment: so ... what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: i want the contents in my second file to be in a single column not divided into two rows

Comment: that is your expectation. What part of the coding are you having trouble with? Since you managed to write this code, you no doubt know what it does and how it can be altered?

Comment: the content from file one is being copied into string just fine

Comment: but  while writing that content from string to file it is not giving me dedicated results

Comment: Don't link an image to text - include the text (its not like that is a lot of data). Your description is confusing.  Please include your expected output and your actual output so you can point to how it is not behaving as expected.